# Seemingly valid trig substitution gives a different answer

Tags: calculus

Trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}dx
$$
I attempted two solutions, one of them is correct. I am unable to identify why my second solution lends an incorrect  answer although I have reviewed it over and over again and I am convinced that it is generally correct due to how very similar the two answers look. Below, is my two solutions. I need help finding what went wrong and why aren't they giving the same output.

**First solution (correct)**
$$
I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}dx
$$
Complete the square:
$$
=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-4}}dx
$$
Let $x-2=2\sec{\theta}$, hence $x=2\sec{\theta}+2$ and $dx=2\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta$ and rewrite the integral:
$$=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\sec{\theta}+2-2)^2-4}}2\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta$$
Simplify:
$$=\int\frac{1}{2\tan{\theta}}2\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta=\int\sec{\theta}d\theta$$
Integrate:
$$=\ln{|\sec{\theta}+\tan{\theta}|+C}$$
Rewrite in terms of $x$:
$$\ln{\left|\frac{x-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}{2}\right|+C}$$
**Second solution**
$$
I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}dx
$$
Factorize:
$$
=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x(\frac{1}{4}x-1)}}dx
$$
Let $x=4\sec^2{\theta}$ and $dx=8\sec^2{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta$ and rewrite the integral:
$$=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4(4\sec^2{\theta})(\frac{1}{4}(4\sec^2{\theta})-1)}}8\sec^2{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta$$
Simplify:
$$
=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{16\sec^2{\theta}{\tan^2{\theta}}}}8\sec^2{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta
$$
$$=2\int\sec{\theta}d\theta$$

Integrate:
$$=2\ln{\left|\sec{\theta}+\tan{\theta}\right|+C}$$

Rewrite in terms of $x$:
$$2\ln{\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x-4}}{2}\right|}+C$$

As you can see, the answer in terms of $\theta$ is off by a factor of 2, I tried rewriting both answers in terms of $x$, equated them then did the math; The result of which was:
$$\ln{\left|\frac{x-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}{2}\right|+C}=2\ln{\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x-4}}{2}\right|}+C$$
$$x^4-4x^3-6x^2+17x+10=0$$
Which I didn't pursue any further for how unpromising it appears.

Help is very well appreciated :)

Comment: Oh yea, mistake

Comment: The problem is about $x$, but your 1st answer is about $\theta$, so it isn't a correct answer to the question. To be correct, an answer must be about $x$, not some other letter.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, the first answer is correct once rewritten in $x$. I will clarify it in the question.

Comment: Also, the $+C$ in the 1st answer needn't equal the $+C$ in the 2nd.

Comment: But most important, aren't $(x-2)/2 + \sqrt{x^2-4x}/2$ and $(\sqrt x/2+\sqrt{x-4}/2)^2$ equal?

Comment: I can not tell if they are, I couldn't get them to match, and when I tried solving for $x$ I got that 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: Then you made some mistake in your algebra. Try again. They should match.

Comment: Ok, I will redo it again, it's comforting to hear that the integrals are not incorrect.

Comment: You were right, it was a mistake in my algebra, I eliminated the denominators when I copied both expressions ending up without the / 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small hint: $2\log(X) = \log(X^2)$. So evaluate the square of the argument in the right side and you will see that it actually evaluates to the argument in the left side.

Comment: That's what I did to get the long polynomial at the end

Comment: I’ll show you:
$$(\sqrt {x}/2 + \sqrt{x-4}/2)^2 = x/4 + (x-4)/4 + 2/4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x-4} = (x-2)/2 + 1/2\sqrt{x^2-4x}$$

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing, they are indeed equal. I don't know how it went past me. Thanks to everyone. Now I need help on who should I accept as the correct answer since everyone gave really insightful help. :)

Comment: Which answer to accept is entirely up to you. If you can't make a decision, toss a coin. In the grand scheme of things, it's not worth worrying about, and I'm sure no one will hold a grudge against you.

Comment: Also I’m sure noone cares a lot about those credits, so pick whatever you find explains the whole thing best.

Comment: I don't care either, but please accept one of them so things are not left hanging.

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions are both correct. As $\theta$ is different each time it is hardly surprising you get different expressions. You need to get it in terms of  $x$, which you did. Leaving out the constant the 2 solutions are as you say
$$\ln{\left|\frac{x-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x}}{2}\right|}$$ and $$2\ln{\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x-4}}{2}\right|}$$.
These are equal as you verify using $2\ln{y}=\ln{y^2}$.